# eureka client not registering when configured with config server

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to use spring data microservice to connect to config server to get mysql properties.

I can see the service can talk to config server and get the properties loaded.. but it is unable to register in Eureka after that. Also, discovery client is unable to make heartbeats

It works and registers fine when config server dependency is removed and all the properties lie in application.yml file

Any help on this is really appreciated.

**Config server Configuration**

```
server:
  port: 8888
spring: 
  application:
    name: configserver  
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: <github path>
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
```

**Eureka server Configuration**

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8761} # Indicate the default PORT where this service will be started

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false # telling the server not to register himself in the service
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

**Discovery Client configuration**

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
  application:
    name: inventoryservice
server:
  port: 8098

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/

logging:
  file: error.log
```

Stacktrace of exception -

```
2018-05-08 16:47:41.734  INFO 54300 --- [main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application inventoryservice with eureka with status UP
2018-05-08 16:47:41.735  INFO 54300 --- [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1525778261735, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
2018-05-08 16:47:41.737  INFO 54300 --- [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_INVENTORYSERVICE/localhost:inventoryservice:8098: registering service...
2018-05-08 16:47:41.857  INFO 54300 --- [main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8098 (http)
2018-05-08 16:47:41.858  INFO 54300 --- [main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8098
2018-05-08 16:47:41.862  INFO 54300 --- [main] c.m.cloud.InventoryServiceApplication    : Started InventoryServiceApplication in 17.788 seconds (JVM running for 18.544)
2018-05-08 16:47:43.830 ERROR 54300 --- [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.register(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:798) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator$1.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:88) [eureka-client-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.3.jar:4.5.3]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    ... 30 common frames omitted

2018-05-08 16:47:43.831  WARN 54300 --- [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2018-05-08 16:47:45.162  INFO 54300 --- [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] inMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin : Application shutdown requested.
2018-05-08 16:47:45.163  INFO 54300 --- [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5c153b9e: startup date [Tue May 08 16:47:33 IST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7770f470
2018-05-08 16:47:45.163  INFO 54300 --- [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Unregistering application inventoryservice with eureka with status DOWN
2018-05-08 16:47:45.164  WARN 54300 --- [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1525778265164, current=DOWN, previous=UP]
2018-05-08 16:47:45.164  INFO 54300 --- [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Shutting down DiscoveryClient ...
2018-05-08 16:47:45.164  INFO 54300 --- [RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Unregistering ...
2018-05-08 16:47:45.837 ERROR 54300 --- [DiscoveryClient-InstanceInfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error
```

Comment: have u try using this 
  `spring:                                                                                         
    cloud:
      config:
        uri: http://localhost:8888/configserver`                                         
 in your Discovery Client configuration?

Comment: @Yogendra Mishra: yes but it did not work. I tried using eureka first approach also, Even that did not work

Comment: Which version of Spring-Cloud you are using? is it Dalston.RELEASE?

Comment: I think making `eureka.client.fetch-registry= true` in Discovery Client configuration will resolve the issue.

Comment: can you please share the pom.xml or build.gradle of discovery server

Comment: Can you try moving `spring:` properties to bootstrap for discovery client?